# Apache Universal Redirect - Except For Certain Sub-Domain

Tags: redirect, apache2

I have a configuration file for an Apache web server.

It simply has one Redirect line in it now.  The idea is that any domain name hosted on the server will redirect this path to webmail:

Redirect /mail https://www.example.com/webmail/

However, I am attempting to setup Mozilla Thunderbird's autoconfig capabilities to make it easier to configure that application automatically.  Unfortunately - I have to put the XML file in a /mail/ directory and so it is triggering the above Redirect rule.

Is there any way that the same functionality can be applied - for everything but a single sub-domain - something like "autoconfig.example.com"?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  While it is not specifically for a sub-domain, I found the way to set it so it must match ONLY the redirect.  If anything is after the redirect, it ignores it (doesn't use it)

RedirectMatch /mail$ https://www.example.com/webmail/

Using RedirectMatch instead of Redirect allows for the regex to be added - and the "$" at the end of the /mail ensures that it only matches this specific phrase and nothing more.